# 雷 vs 雷聲 vs 雷鳴 for "thunder", which is most common?

Tags: word-choice, mandarin, synonyms

There's a huge thunderstorm here in Kaohsiung right now so I thought I would learn the word for "thunder".

I can find three words in the dictionary and wonder which I should use for everybody to understand me:

- 雷 léi
- 雷聲 léishēng
- 雷鳴 léimíng

I know often single-character words are technically correct but not usually used on their own. But also quite a few are, such as 雨.

Also some words are poetic or technical or archaic or dialectal, etc.

Which of these three words should I use most of the time for "thunder"?

Comment: Use 雷聲. 雷鳴 is used in written texts while 雷 is the simplified form and is usually to form compound words.

Comment: Good question, and how to distinguish between thunder and lightning in Chinese. I guess 打雷 is best for thunder (although I feel like it could just as easily meaning lightning).

Comment: *"how to distinguish between thunder and lightning in Chinese"* we know the fact that we "看見閃電 (see lighting)" and "聽到行雷(hear thunder)"

Comment: Just an advice: if you don't know which one is more used, type it on Baidu or Google and see which one returns the most results.

Comment: @EnricoBrasil: This method is good unless one of the options is a single character in which case it always gets more hits whether or not it's much used as a word on its own or mostly in compounds.

Answer (score 2):

打雷 is the best for describing action.
現在外面正在打雷 There's thunder outside right now

雷聲 is also good for describing what you hear
我剛被雷聲嚇到 I was surprised (shocked) by the sound of the thunder

雷 by itself means thunder, and used a little less often
but it also means bomb as in 地雷.
這家店有雷. This store is a bomb. (When joking to friends that this food store sucks and is like stepping on a bomb/mine)

You could say, 外面有雷 There is thunder outside
But it would sound awkward, the common phrase would be, 外面正在打雷

Answer (score 1):

> Which of these three words should I use most of the time for "thunder"?

**行雷/打雷** is the most common term for " thunder"( v with no obj) [*it thunders*]

雷 (n) thunder

雷電 common term for " thunder and lightning " (n)

**行雷/打雷** verb with no object for " thunder" : [*it thunders*]

行雷閃電 - common phrase for " thundering and lightning"(v- no obj)

雷聲 = sound of thunder; 雷響 = booming of thunder; 雷嗚 = roar of thunder

Example sentences:

- 看見閃電之後數秒才聽到**行雷/打雷** - a few seconds after seeing  lightning, you'll hear **thunder**
- 看見閃電之後數秒才聽到**雷聲** - a few seconds after seeing  lightning, you'll hear the **sound of thunder**
- 看見閃電之後數秒才聽到**雷響** - a few seconds after seeing  lightning, you'll hear the **booming of thunder**
- 電閃後必有**雷嗚** - after  flash of lightning,  **roar of thunder** will come

*雷嗚 is mostly used in poetic sense*

*It might sounds strange, for "lighting strike", 雷轟, 雷擊, 雷打 or 雷劈 is more popular than 電擊 or 電殛; meanwhile 電殛 also means "electrocute"*

Comment: Just some tips on your English translations. We don't really say "it thunders" in the same way we say "it rains" or "it snows". Maybe some people do. I don't know if we really say "roar" either though it's perfect for the sound. For thunder we say "crash". I edited some other stuff for you. Great answer - thanks!

Comment: " [it thunders]  was not in any speech, it was from the dictionary just to illustrate thunder as a verb

Comment: 行雷 is more like Cantonese